# i am having a button(for the user to select file from file chooser) and a editext(to show the user the the path of selected file) how can i do that?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

//after user press select file btn

```
public void onClick(View v) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                        + "/myFolder/");
                    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/*");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));

                    //String path = uri.getPath();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),path +"Selected File",
                    //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

//after selected the file from the file chooser

```
static final int FILE_SELECTION_RESULT = 1; 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        EditText selectedFile; 

        if (requestCode == FILE_SELECTION_RESULT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                String filePath = data.getData().getPath();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //selectedFile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                //selectedFile.setText(data.getExtras().getString("selected_file"));

                }
            }
        }
```

// i am not sure that i am doing this wrong or correct, please help me.. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not open a folder with Intent. To solve this problem, you have two way:
1- force your users to install OI file explorer, an open source lite file browser that can handle ACTION_VIEW on folders, or
2- Write an activity to handle this action. MapsForge open source library has a simple file chooser. Take a look at that: https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/

Comment: ..bro, do you know how can i delete the file with the path that i selected from the oi file explorer?

Comment: 'File file = new File(PATH/TO/FILE); if( file.exists() ) { file.delete(); }'

Comment: Thanks a lot bro..You solved my problem again..now i got a new problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515340/is-these-codes-correct-to-list-down-all-the-permission-required-by-installed-app) @Ali Behzadian Nejad

Answer (score 0):

Instead of startActivity call `startActivityForResult`.

And inside `onActivityResult` just set the filePath to `editText`

for more information on file chooser android look [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/03/pick-file-using-intentactiongetcontent.html)